# How to get terms or taxonomies only for custom post types

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, wordpress-plugin-creation

I have an array of post types and I want to fetch all categories or terms which only belong to these post types. Like product post type have a category with the name **"product_cat"**  I used `get_terms()` but it returns all available terms. If I use `get_categories()`  It returns only terms of **post** type.

```
$post_types = array('post', 'product', 'page');
```

Comment: Please share examples of your code.

Comment: $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'taxonomy'  => 'product_cat'
        );
        $terms = get_terms( $args );

If I use this so this is working fine but I want to get terms without giving taxonomies I get all post_types with get_post_types() function and now I want to get terms of these post types.

Answer (score 0):

You can to get it next - example of getting all custom taxonomy `brand_categories` of custom post `brand`

```php
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'brand',
  'taxonomy'  => 'brand_categories'
);
$categories = get_terms( $args );
```

Comment: Yes, that is ok but what if have more post types and I want to manage them and do not know the taxonomy, Is it work if give only post_type

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code to get categories of post type product -

```
$args = array(
 'post_type' => 'product',
 'taxonomy'  => 'product_cat'
);
$categories = get_terms( $args );
```

Comment: Yes, that is ok but what if have more post types and I want to manage them and do not know the taxonomy, Is it work if give only post_type

Answer (score 0):

For retrieving the categories need a taxonomy.
You must use the taxonomy without taxonomy can not get term details.